# How to judge webrtc fec effect

Tags: webrtc

How to judge webrtc fec effect, use recovery rate or anti-packet loss rate？

When using webrtc flexfec to play video, the packet loss rate and delay are simulated. According to the bandwidth detected by webrtc, the specific effect of fec cannot be determined now. How to count its anti-packet loss effect?